# Is it possible to call a property setter with a different type as the property's type itself?

Tags: c#, setter

I have a Layer class with a unique Name property serving as identifier:

```
public class Layer {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    // Various other properties
    ...
}
```

Furthermore I have a DiagramHandler which handles (among other things) the layer management

```
public class DiagramHandler {
    private Layer _activeLayer;
    public Layer ActiveLayer {
        get { return _activeLayer; }
        set {
            Layer layer = DiagramLayers.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name.Equals(value.Name);
            if (layer != null) {
                _activeLayer = layer;
            } else {
                // Error handling
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Layer> DiagramLayers { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I have stored all possible layers in a collection within the handler and a single currently active one in its own property. If the latter one gets set, one of the Layers in the collection is identified and set as the active layer. Now, as I actually only need the layer name to properly identify the layer I wonder whether I could pass over just a string to the ActiveLayer's setter instead of a whole layer. So I could do this:

```
// Yes, the DiagramHandler is a singleton
DiagramHandler.Instance.ActiveLayer = "Background";
```

instead of having to do this:

```
DiagramHandler.Instance.ActiveLayer = new Layer() { Name = "Background" };
```

I'm aware I could use a setter function (which I actually do right now) but I'd prefer the use of a plain property setter and was curious if there's a language feature I just don't know or if there's a more elegant and nice solution.

Comment: You can use an implicit operator to handle conversion from a string to a Layer object. Lookup implicit conversions. You might also want to make the Name property on Layer immutable, if it's serving as the identity.

Comment: Why not add a second `string` propertly called `ActiveLayerName` and use that for getting / setting the layer by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not possible. You can have an implicit conversion overload on your `Layer` class (very smelly - I am not recommending this!), or have the setter method as you currently have.

Your solution is the best way to approach the problem, no hidden syntactic sugar, unfortunately!

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to create a [custom conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) between `string` and `Layer`, assuming that Layer is a type you can modify and not a 3rd party type.

```
public static explicit operator Layer(string layerName)
{
    return new Layer { Name = layerName };
}

Layer myLayer = (Layer)"Background";
```

You can also use the `implicit` keyword to avoid requiring the explicit cast.

Keep in mind, though, that this is a global operator, not only part of your property.

A more localized alternative is instead of properties, use a method like `SetActiveLayer` that has two overloads - one that accepts Layer and one that accepts a string and creates the layer.

Comment: Even though you were faster and gave an example I will mark Rob's response as answer as he stated cleary there is no "better" approach as my current one, which was exactly what I was asking for, but thank you for the answer nonetheless, it's much appreciated. Btw. I actually do use a SetActiveLayer method currently as I've written in the end of my post ;) No need for an overload taking a Layer as argument though.

Comment: While the implicit conversion solution is correct and will work, it is bad design, because it is no longer clear what ActiveLayer is, is it a Layer or is it a String? SetActiveLayer() or ActiveLayerName is the way to go. It is self documenting.

Comment: I dislike having two properties with a setter and different types because it's unclear what the canonical property is.